# How do I run async work on text field changes but only after some seconds when the user is done changing the field?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a field in a form that takes in a username. When this value changes, some asynchronous work runs. Right now the asynchronous work is firing on every letter change. How do I make it so that it only fires some amount of seconds after the user has changed the field and when the user isn't making any more changes?

```
TextField(
    controller: userController,
    onChanged: (text) {
      asyncWorkThatDoesntNeedToBeAwaited(text);
    },
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a package name [easy_debounce](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_debounce).

Here is an example of it in use - [repo](https://github.com/SnippetCoders/flutter_debounce_search/tree/main)